# How to reset rotation of a UV-Island?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I accidentially rotated an UV-Island

[image]

Is there a way to reset the rotation to 0 so that it is horizontal again like the other islands?

I know I could just rotate it normaly, but this would not be perfect.

Comment: Unwrap that face again